# Allocate free space to "C" Drive

Tags: windows-xp, hard-drive, disk-space

I am facing a problem of **low space in C drive** where my Windows XP is installed. I have tried **disk cleanup** and other ways.

I would prefer to assign the free space of other partitions to the C partition because I have plenty of space in the D, E and F partitions, about 60 to 70 GB.

I don’t want to format the drive.

Does anybody know how to assign space to C drive?

Comment: Are those other drives partitions on the same drive as C?

Comment: ya all other drives are in same drive.... means my computer have only one hard-drive which contain C,D,E and F drive.... i need to allocate space of F drive to C drive...but don't want to formate my PC...THANKS

Answer (score 6):

You could use a partition editing utility like [gparted](http://gparted.sourceforge.net/) to do this. It will allow you to make your d,e or f partitions smaller and give that space to c.

Would be wise to ensure you have a good backup first, but I've used gparted many times for many years and never had an issue with this sort of task.

Comment: i have seen...size of software is very big 129.4 mb.....due to slaw internet speed i can't download it now.....i will download it tomorrow.......btw,.......thak you so much for replying.......

Comment: hello i have downloaded software and i got one .iso file i have extract it using PowerISO but.......i don't know how to install these software....there is no setup.exe or exe for setup software.

Comment: Burn the iso to a CD and then boot from that CD.

Comment: @Chris_K: I have downloaded GParted and mount using magic disk. But it seems there is not exe file i the image file so, how do I install it on Windows 7?

Comment: You'll want to create a boot disk. A small one is http://gparted.sourceforge.net/livecd.php

Comment: I was going to say this but you beat me to the punch.

Answer (score 3):

As well as the gparted option (or similar software to resize partitions) you could use Windows' dynamic spanned volumes to merge one of the other partitions into C:. For instance to get rid of F: and merge the space it uses into C:

1. open disk management (right-click "my computer", choose "manage", and the disk manager should be available in the control panel app that comes up)
2. convert the disk to a dynamic volume if it isn't one already (right-click the drive and it should be an option on that menu)
3. move all the stuff off F: to somewhere else
4. delete F:
5. right-click C: and select "expand volume"
6. select what space you want to add (it will default to adding all the currently free space, i.e. the space that was taken up by F: until recently)

If you want to keep F: but just make it smaller then alter the above a little:

- in step 6 just select some of the space that is now free instead of all of it
- add step 7: recreate F: using the free space that is left and move the files that you moved off F: in step 3 back onto this new F: partition

This technique has the advantage of not using any 3rd party tools as it is all built into Windows - while gparted is a very reliable tool generally I have experienced trouble with Windows not liking having had its system volume resized (I've had it work fine, but sometimes Windows won't boot afterwards despite the filesystem being valid as other Windows installs can read from the partition without issue).

Of course the disadvantage of this method is that by converting to a "dynamic disk" you potentially lose compatibility with other software you might want to use in future. Installing Linux on the same drive for dual-booting is one thing that won't work (see [Ubuntu 9.10+Windows 7 dual boot, dynamic disks](https://superuser.com/questions/89304/ubuntu-9-10win7-dual-boot-dynamic-disks) for instance). Also, dynamic disks are not available in the "home" editions of Windows (well, the feature isn't present under XP Home - that may have changed in Vista or 7), and by having one volume spread between two ends of your drive (rather than one continuous block) things will be a little less deficienct as the drive heads will be moving further then they otherwise would at times.

One last point: if you add an extra disk, also set as a dynamic disk, you can extend C: onto the space on that instead of resizing existing partitions (in fact you could expand all your partitions into space on the second drive if you wanted). *This is not generally recommended though* as it is just a JBOD arrangement so you get all the problems of RAID0 (if one drive dies, all your C: is likely to be lost) without the speed improvement it can offer.

*Oh, and a final last point: even though this is almost certainly a safe operation, it is still a good idea to make sure your backups are up-to-date before proceeding if only for the sake of healthy paranoia, because if something* does *go wrong it could badly corrupt the entire filesystem you are working on.*

Comment: i can not found how to change volume to "dynamic volume" i have right clicked drive letter in (Computer managements windows==>"Disk Managment" )..but i could not find .......i also could not find "Expand Volume" when i right clicked "Drive Letter C:"......Thanks.........

Comment: If you have neither the "expand volume" or "convert to dynamic disk" options, then you probably have XP Home Edition, which I think does not support these features.

Comment: I was going to say this too but you also beat me to the punch.

Answer (score 2):

I have tried **MiniTool Partition Wizard** which is working fine and I have successfully extended my C drive using the software [here](http://www.partitionwizard.com/free-partition-manager.html).